# APK File size is big in react native

Tags: react-native

I developed some very basic application with 2 screens with no added libraries?
When i tried to extract APK file it is around 22MB .

Another guy developed same application in Ionic which has just 9 MB of APK file.
Can you please tell how can we reduce the size of APK in react native?
If you can give some hint I will explore further?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Hermes? _"Hermes will result in improved start-up time, decreased memory usage, and *smaller app size*."_ https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### create an APK for each CPU

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

> You can create an APK for each CPU by changing the following line in android/app/build.gradle:

```
- ndk {
-   abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
- }
- def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
+ def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```

### use hermes

https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#docsNav

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will explore further on it.